# Add a column of minutes to a datetime in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, math

I have a dataframe with a start time and the length of operation. I'm trying to figure out out to add the length (in minutes) to the start time in order to figure out the end time of the session. I've run a few different variations of the same general idea and keep getting the same error, "unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: Series". The code extract is below:

```
data= {'Name': ['John', 'Peter'],
    'Start' : [2, 2],   
    'Length': [120, 90],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['Length'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Length'])
df["tdiffinmin"] = df['Start'].apply(lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(minutes = df["Length"]))
```

Ive also tried the follow as other methods of doing this math and keep getting similar errors.

```
df["tdiffinmin"] = df['Start'].apply(lambda x: x -pd.DateOffset(minutes = df["Length"])) 
df["tdiffinmin"] = (df['Start']. + timedelta(minutes = df["Length"])).dt.total_seconds() / 60
df['tdiffinmin'] = df['Start'] - pd.DateOffset(minutes = df["Length"])
```

The full code reads from a data set (excel sheet or CSV), populates a Dataframe, and this is some of the math I am doing. Originally it was done with Start and Stop times, so I know something similar is possible. In the dataset, Length is in minutes and Start is a date and time, so datetime is necessary.

Comment: I don't really know what time `2` is supposed to be... That being said, since you really don't have dates it's unclear why `datetime`/`timedelta` logic is even necessary. Work in hours or minutes and you can do trivial addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert `Length` into `timedelta`, not `datetime`:

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['Length'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Length'], unit='min')

df['tdiffinmin'] = df['Start'] + df['Length']
```

Output:

```
    Length   Name                         Start                    tdiffinmin
0 02:00:00   John 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002 1970-01-01 02:00:00.000000002
1 01:30:00  Peter 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002 1970-01-01 01:30:00.000000002
```

Comment: since the OP wants minutes, I think it should be `pd.to_datetime(df['Start']*60e9)` as `pandas` interprets the `[2, 2]` to be nanoseconds.